# How can I replace the values in WP_Term?

Tags: terms

`WP_Term` outputs:

```
    WP_Term Object
(
    [term_id] => 3
    [name] => Public
    [slug] => public
    [term_group] => 0
    [term_taxonomy_id] => 3
    [taxonomy] => category
    [description] => 
    [parent] => 0
    [count] => 10
    [filter] => raw
)
```

What is the best way to replace the values for `[name] => Public` or `slug] => public` dynamically? Is `array_replace` the best option? The objective is rather than use `unset( $terms[$key] );` for example, I'd like to replace/rename the values in the array.

Answer (score 0):

To replace values in a WP_Term object, you can modify its properties directly. For example:

```
$term = get_term( $term_id, $taxonomy );

if ( ! empty( $term ) && ! is_wp_error( $term ) ) {
    $term->name = 'New Term Name';
    $term->slug = 'new-term-slug';
    $term->description = 'New Term Description';
}
```

In this example, the **get_term()** function is used to retrieve a WP_Term object based on the term ID and taxonomy. If the term is found and is not an error, its properties **name, slug**, and **description** are updated with new values.

Note that after updating the properties, you need to use the **wp_update_term()** function to persist the changes in the database:

```
$update_result = wp_update_term( $term->term_id, $taxonomy, array(
    'name' => $term->name,
    'slug' => $term->slug,
    'description' => $term->description,
) );

if ( is_wp_error( $update_result ) ) {
    // error updating term
} else {
    // term updated successfully
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `wp_update_term` overrides values indiscriminately. Is there a way to filter in on the fly similar to the `the_content` hook?